# Contar ocorrências em uma lista de acordo com prefixos

Tags: python, python-2.7

imaginemos que tenho uma lista

```
['rato', 'roeu', 'rolha', 'rainha', 'rei', 'russia']
```

e outra lista com prefixos

```
['ro', 'ra', 'r']
```

como faço para contar quantas vezes está cada prefixos dentro da primeira lista?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
words = ['rato', 'roeu', 'rolha', 'rainha', 'rei', 'russia']
pref = ['ro', 'ra', 'r']

contTotal = 0
for p in pref:
    cont = 0
    for w in words:
        if w.startswith(p):
            cont+=1
    contTotal += cont
    print p + ' aparece ' + str(cont) + ' vezes nas palavras como prefixo'
print 'O numero total de vezes é ' + str(contTotal)
```

Comment: Provavelmente há uma maneira, utilizando menos código, para fazer isto também.

Comment: Esse seu código não verifica corretamente, pois ele não está apenas pegando o prefixo, mas qualquer ocorrência dentro da palavra.

Comment: Verdade, falha minha :P, vou ajustar

Comment: O seu contador está sendo zerado também, deveria iniciar fora do loop

Comment: Fiz desta maneira pois não ficou claro se queria contar o total ou o número de ocorrências por prefixo. Deixei as 2 formas :)

Comment: funciona perfeitamente :) obrigada, mas o contTotal neste caso nao era preciso

Answer (score 7):

*One-liner* funcional abominável com `sum` e `map`:

```
sum(map(lambda x: 1 if x.startswith(tuple(pref)) else 0, words))
```

Abominável *one-liner* com `reduce`:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + 1 if y.startswith(tuple(pref)) else x, words, 0)
```

:)

---

## Update:

Conforme requisitos do OP, ainda mais abominável *one-liner* das neves:

```
map(lambda p: reduce(lambda c, w: c + 1 if w.startswith(p) else c, words, 0), pref)
```

Exemplo menos forçado:

```
def countPrefix(words, prefix):
    return len([1 for w in words if w.startswith(prefix)]) 

[countPrefix(words, p) for p in pref]
```

Resultado:

```
[2, 2, 6]
```

Comment: isto so me dá o numero de ocorrencias de um dos prefixos, neste caso dá-me só 6.. eu preciso do numero de ocorrencias de cada um dos prefixos

Comment: o exemplo menos forçado não consigo por a funcionar.. nao sei como você fez

Comment: Qual é a sua dúvida? Estou declarando uma função para contar a quantidade de um determinado prefixo em uma lista de palavras. Na sequência temos uma *list comprehension* solta aplicando a função para todos os prefixos declarados. Para obter o resultado você pode, por exemplo, jogá-lo em uma variável e mandar imprimí-lo (veja  [exemplo](https://ideone.com/9kYUrr))

Comment: ah ok, já percebi, obrigada!

Answer (score 6):

Eu poderia fazer desse jeito:

```
>>> palavras = ['rato', 'roeu', 'rolha', 'rainha', 'rei', 'russia']
>>> prefixos = ['ro', 'ra', 'r']
>>> len(filter(None, [p if p.startswith(tuple(prefixos)) else None for p in palavras]))
6
```

*Neste caso para saber quantas palavras tiveram uma das ocorrências da lista.

Comment: Notei aqui que você pode evitar esse `filter` simplesmente usando `[p for p in palavras if p.startswith(tuple(prefixos))]`.

Answer (score 6):

Assumindo-se que não existe nenhuma "hierarquia" entre os prefixos (ex.: toda palavra que começa com `ro` *também* começa com `r`), uma maneira simples e direta é usando o [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). Ele vai combinar cada elemento da primeira lista com cada elemento da segunda lista. Então basta filtrar aqueles que o segundo é prefixo do primeiro, e contar:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> palavras = ['rato', 'roeu', 'rolha', 'rainha', 'rei', 'russia']
>>> prefixos = ['ro', 'ra', 'r']
>>> len([palavra for palavra,prefixo in itertools.product(palavras, prefixos) if palavra.startswith(prefixo)])
10
```

Note que as 4 primeiras palavras foram contadas duas vezes (pois elas começam tanto com `ro`/`ra` quanto com `r`). Para uma solução que só conte cada palavra uma única vez, veja por exemplo as respostas do [Orion](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57381/215) e [Anthony Accioly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57384/215) (a do [Dherik](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57373/215) faz ambos, e ainda conta as ocorrências por prefixo).

Comment: eu preciso que ele me conte as ocorrencias de cada um em parte, peço desculpa nao especifiquei bem isso. Neste caso dava 2,2 e 6